# Use 'open' command on OS X from eshell

Tags: eshell, osx

Inside of eshell I get the error

```
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error - 10810 for the file ...
```

if I try to use the `open` command on OS X. What's going on here and is there a workaround?

**Edit:** The error code was 10810 (not 100810). I also get the same error in emacs in `shell`, `term`, and `ansi-term`. `open` does work for me in iTerm2 and terminal. I've tried this on pdf and png files.

Comment: I can run `open` on a PDF file from eshell, and it opens in Preview. What kind of file are you trying it on?

Comment: Does the same command work without error in Terminal.app?  Does it work inside `M-x shell`?  Are you sure you haven't made a typo in the error code? Googling suggests `10810` is more likely than `100810`.

Comment: @legoscia I tried a PDF, same error. @deprecated It does work in Terminal.app but not in `M-x shell`. I fixed the error number, thanks.

Comment: The 10810 is a generic error. More specifics are written to /var/log/system.log, which may explain the true source of open errors. It could be as simple as filename error or as complex as restarting finder or window server.

Comment: It works out of the box for me using the most recent public release of Emacs -- i.e., 24.5 -- on Snow Leopard 10.6.8.

Comment: If the problem happens on all those emacs-related terminals but not on any of the regular OS terminals, then my guess would be on an environment variable.